# What am I missing here, basic Twilio outgoing call? (Very descriptive)

Tags: android, heroku, twilio

So I am editing the Android Twilio Test Client to ensure that my server and TwiML is set up properly before adding it to my other mobile app. This is my first time using Twilio so I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

I set up my server using heroku, the mobile app is set to point to "../herokuurl/token". I used https://github.com/twilio/mobile-quickstart to set it up. When I go to that URL I do indeed see the temporary long string to be used as the capability token.

I have tried with both my verified real cell number and the number assigned to my twilio account, no luck with either (which should I be using, trying to do outgoing calls from mobile app only)

My TwiML app points to "../herokuurl/call". and HTTP GET is set. The heroku server is set up with the proper account sid, token and app sid. Does the Client matter? (Currently set to 'jenny')

Basically, at this point what happens when I run the mobile app, it seems to get the capability token but doesn't connect the call it just disconnects the call where when I run the sample mobile app with http://twilioclientazure.azurewebsites.net/Client/Token set it does connect the call.

I have to assume I am missing something very simple, I am just trying to create a basic outgoing call. This has been driving me nuts I have been at this for days trying to figure it out. If someone could help me out I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Can you verify that you've set up a TwiML App in your twilio account dashboard and pointed the Voice Request URL to a URL that returns TwiML?  If you have can you update your question with that TwiML?  Also, can you add the Java from your Android app to your question?

Comment: @DevinRader this is a link to my TwiML configuration and then below is everything in my server.py page excluding the Account_SID, auth token, and APP_SID.

http://i59.tinypic.com/n5ijv4.png
http://pastie.org/pastes/9955300/text

Comment: @DevinRader sorry, forgot to mention. Its the Xamarin/Twilio Test Client app which can be found at https://components.xamarin.com/view/twilio-client and the path to the code (C#) is 'twilio-client-1.2.zip\twilio-client-1.2\samples\TwilioClientTest.Android' basically I'm just trying to replace that app with my TwiML to test that the server is generating compatibility tokens and everything correctly, then I will switch it over to my mobile app that I have written.

Comment: When I make a GET request to your heroku app and pass in test To and From querysting params I get an error saying that the CLIENT global variable has not been defined.

Comment: @DevinRader should be there now, sorry I was experimenting with it last night. Do you have hangouts or anything so that we could communicate more quickly?